# ¿Como validar correctamente un email con expresiones regulares?

Tags: javascript

muy buenas estoy realizando un formulario con validaciones de expresión regular el problema que tengo es que cuando quiero validar el campo email me parecen esta serie de fallos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los mensajes de los fallos que aparecen en el recuadro son estos en cuestion:

> Uncaught TypeError: campo is null

> validaCampos file:///f:/javascript recuperacion/ejercicioformular/js.js:92

> validador file:///f:/javascript recuperacion/ejercicio formulario/js.js:36

> file:///f:/javascript recuperacion/ejercicio formulario/js.js:3

> onload file:///f:/javascript recuperacion/ejercicio formulario/js.js:3

> EventHandlerNonNull* file:///f:/javascript recuperacion/ejercicio formulario/js.js:2

Lo que tiene que hacer el formulario en cuestión es validar los datos para poder darme la opción de enviarlo. Si elimino el campo email y valido solo los otros 4 si me deja enviarlo por lo que el error solo se encuentra en ese campo, aunque por si acaso voy a pasar el código entero ya que como bien se ve en la imagen marca varios errores en diferentes lineas de código.

```
    window.onload = function(){
        document.getElementById('btnValidar').onclick = function(){validador()};
    
    }
        var arrayFallos =[];
    
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        
     function validador(){
            
            arrayFallos = []
    
            var campoNombre = document.getElementById('nombre');
            var expNombre = new RegExp('^[A-Z]{1}[A-Za-z áéúíó ñ]{2,14}$');//nombre que comprueba las vocales , que emppiece por mayuscula y que vaya de 2 a 14 caracteres
            validaCampos(expNombre,campoNombre);
           
    
            var campoEdad = document.getElementById('edad');
            var expEdad = new RegExp('^([1][8-9]|[2-5][0-9]|[6][0-5])$');//va desde los 18 hasta los 65
            validaCampos(expEdad, campoEdad);
        
    
            var campoDNI = document.getElementById('DNI');
            var expDNI = new RegExp('^[0-9]{8}[A-Z]{1}$');//valida un DNI español
            validaCampos(expDNI,campoDNI);
    
    
            var campotlf = document.getElementById('tlf');
            var exptlf = new RegExp('^[679]{1}[0-9]{8}$');//valida numeros de telefono movil
            validaCampos(exptlf,campotlf);
    
    
            var campoemail = document.getElementById('email');
            var expemail = new RegExp('^(.+)@(\\S+)$');
            validaCampos(expemail,campoemail);
    
        console.log("Array fallos en el siguiente log");
        console.log(arrayFallos);
    
        if(arrayFallos.length==0){
            alert("Formulario completo puede enviar");
            document.getElementById("Enviar").disabled=false;
            document.getElementById("Enviar").type='submit';
        }else{
            var fallos = "";
            for(var i=0;i<arrayFallos.length;i++){
                fallos += arrayFallos[i].name+"\n"; 
            }
            arrayFallos[0].focus();
            alert("Los campos: \n"+fallos+"\nNo cumplen los requisitos");
        }
function validaCampos(expresion, campo){

    var idcampo = campo.id

    if(expresion.test(campo.value)){
        console.log("Si "+campo , idcampo);
        return true;
    }else{
        console.log("NO "+campo, idcampo, campo.value);
    
        arrayFallos.push(campo);

    switch(idcampo){

        case 'nombre':
            window.alert("Error en el campo "+idcampo+" : \n\n. valor no valido");
        break;
        case 'edad':
            window.alert("Error en el campo "+idcampo+" : \n\n valor no valido");
        break;
        case 'DNI':
            window.alert("Error en el campo "+idcampo+" : \n\n valor no valido");
        break;
        case 'tlf':
            window.alert("Error en el campo "+idcampo+"  \n\n valor no valido");
        break;
        case 'email':
            window.alert("Error en el campo "+idcampo+"  \n\n valor no valido");
        break;

    }
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: La "serie de fallos" que mencionas son prácticamente ilegibles: ponlas _como texto, con formato_. Lee [ask].

Comment: @padaleiana tienes razón ya los he añadido en la pregunta para que se vea mejor el error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para validar los correos yo siempre he usado la expresión regular:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*[.][a-zA-Z]{2,5}
```

Nunca me ha dado problemas.

Un saludo!

Answer (score 2):

no es recomendable hacer esta validación en JavaScript, igualmente una validación básica podría ser
`var expDNI = new RegExp('^[^@]+@[^@]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$');`

Aunque depende la complejidad con la que quieras validar el correo, dejo una web que puede ayudarte según la validación que quieras realizar.

http://w3.unpocodetodo.info/utiles/regex-ejemplos.php?type=email

Comment: Gracias por el consejo aunque me temo que el resultado no ha cambiado